# PHP, Zend Framework: How to set the upload max filesize?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-file

I'm setting the upload max filesize in my form:

```
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setLabel('File to upload:')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
    ->addValidator('Size', false, 10485760) //10MB = 10,485,760 bytes
    ->setMaxFileSize(10485760)
    ->setDestination(APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR);
$this->addElement($file);
```

But I'm getting this error message in my Zend Framework application:

```
Notice: Your 'upload_max_filesize' config setting limits the maximum filesize to '2097152'. You tried to set '10485760' in /location/to/Zend/Form/Element/File.php on line 620
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) is an option in the configuration of PHP itself, and independant of Zend Framework.

If you need to modify that max upload size, you should set it in your `php.ini` file -- note you'll certainly also have to modify [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

Comment: I'm trying to set these in my application.ini file as phpSettings.post_max_size but it doesn't seem to be working, is there another way I can set this? Like some sort of function? set_post_max_size() if such a function exists?

Comment: Not sure this can be configured from the PHP code, actually, as dealing with the uploaded data/file is done by Apache+PHP before your script even really starts...

Comment: I believe you can configure from PHP code, 
ini_set('post_max_size', 10485760);

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work: ini_set('post_max_size', 10485760);

Answer (score 5):

I know this was asked a while ago, but the answer is still relevant, and not actually in this message.

The original poster noted:

```
Notice: Your 'upload_max_filesize' config setting limits the maximum filesize to '2097152'. You tried to set '10485760' in /location/to/Zend/Form/Element/File.php on line 620
```

and in a further note:

> I wasn't able to get this to work: ini_set('post_max_size', 10485760)

Technically the class method setMaxFileSize(), is doing the same thing as that ini_set.

What's largely undocumented, but applies here is that you're allowed to modify this value to anything you want that *doesn't* exceed the value in the php.ini that is read on startup.

For example, the *nix the default value is 2M. If you haven't modified the php.ini, you'll only be able to overwrite this value with a number from 0 to 2097152.

One last note. As mentioned in Pascal MARTIN 's post, it's mentioned that  upload_max_filesize and post_max_size go somewhat hand in hand. Something else to consider is that if you're making these values a somewhat large number, you'll probably want to make sure that your memory_limit value is also considered as you're script will fail due to a memory exhaustion.

Comment: Thanks for the part about not exceeding the value defined in php.ini... you're right, it's not documented at all and it made me waste lot of time! =/

Answer (score 1):

By default **upload_max_filesize** is 2MB in php settings, which is independent of max file size in your upload method. You can increase **upload_max_filesize** in php.ini file.

Or You can also change it in your project **.htaccess** file in that way changes are for that project only.
For example :-

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 25M
php_value memory_limit 100M
```

But Keep **post_max_size** more than **upload_max_filesize** and **memory_limit** should be more than **post_max_size**.

Answer (score -2):

Have you overwritten the default max size in php.ini?